# Disable all triggers during an event in aframe

Tags: javascript, triggers, dom-events, aframe

I have a bunch of triggers on my scene that I need to disable while an audio file is playing.

So the audio file is the first thing playing when opening the scene. During this time I want all the triggers disable so that the user cannot interact with them during the audio time.

Is there a way to disable all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A-Frame master build has `raycaster.enabled` property. So you can `setAttribute('raycaster', 'enabled', false)` temporarily.

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/commit/3ea1b0c32070975b6a8cf5e59d345ac789b930fe

You can also run `.pause()` on components if they implement that handler correctly. If you want to disable triggerdown on vive-controls for example:

```
controllerEl.components['vive-controls'].pause();
```

Comment: `setAttribute('raycaster', 'enabled', false)` didn't work for me. Instead I used `setAttribute('raycaster', {far:'0'})` so that the raycaster is so small it won't intersect anything.

Comment: As mentioned, you need the master build

Comment: URL to the build at this time is https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/f02de02/dist/aframe-master.min.js

Answer (score 0):

By triggers You mean entities with event listeners ?
If so, do they have "pause()" implemented, like ngoKevin suggested [here](http://ngokevin.com/blog/aframe-component/#component-pause-and-component-play-stop-and-go) ?

If not, the idea is to have a

- `play()` method adding event listeners
- `pause()` removing event listeners.

---

Having those, the only thing left is organisation. Either keep all of Your triggers inside a parent entity, and when your sound is playing just iterate through the children like this:

```
document.querySelector("#TriggerParent").children.forEach( (el) => {
   el.pause();
}
```

or You can just grab them by any common attribute, like `querySelector([triggerComponent]);`

---

I guess You can do all of this 'manually' accessing each trigger, but having a dynamic way of enabling/disabling all triggers seems to be a way better concept.

Comment: yeah my bad.. by triggers I mean event listeners and mouseenter events (not sure these can be paused). I was thinking also that perhaps an easier way to solve this would be to shorten the raycaster component during the audio play.